# parse string returns month out of range error

Tags: go

I am going to parse `ps -eo pid,lstart,cmd` output to get process start time

the shell output date format is like this:

`Mon Dec 17 16:20:07 2018`

here is my code,

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "time"
)

func main () {
    myDateString := "Mon Dec 17 16:20:07 2018"
    myDate, err := time.Parse("Mon Jan 02 15:04:05 2016", myDateString)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }
    fmt.Println(myDate)
}
```

go out

```
parsing time "Mon Dec 17 16:20:07 2018": month out of range
0001-01-01 00:00:00 +0000 UTC
```

is there any wrong in my usage?

Comment: @DYZ: 1. That's irrelevant. Changing it to 2006 worked not because of the relationship between the day of the week and the year, but because, just as "Mon" is required in the format string for the DOW, "2006" is required for the year. 2. I didn't remove your comment. It's not even possible for me to remove your comment.

Comment: @DYZ: In fact, it even parses the wrong DOW [perfectly fine](https://play.golang.org/p/7L-xRJhd0Sj), But that's also irrelevant to the question. You can plainly see that the parser only checks for the string `"Mon"`: https://golang.org/src/time/format.go?s=25102:25148#L166  It makes no attempt whatsoever to verify whether or not the the reference date (which is fixed) is "valid" in some sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be

`myDate, err := time.Parse("Mon Jan 02 15:04:05 2006", myDateString)`

instead of

`myDate, err := time.Parse("Mon Jan 02 15:04:05 2016", myDateString)`

Comment: @DYZ: "else" branch? Are you sure you commented on the right post?